# Is there a better/shorter way to write "if string is a single digit"?

Tags: java, if-statement

Is there a better way to write this so it isn't long?

```
if(input.equals("1") || input.equals("2") || input.equals("3")
  || input.equals ("4") || input.equals("5") || input.equals("6")
  || input.equals("7") || input.equals("8") || input.equals("9")) {
    //some code 
}
```

Comment: All you have to do is test the input against a regular expression that define your test values. http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html a nice place to learn about regular expressions .

Comment: In the particular case a regular expression works well, however, another often-used approach is to use [`someCollectionOfChoices.contains(input)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#contains-java.lang.Object); this puts the "decision" into the collection (of strings) itself.

Comment: Try: `if (Character.isDigit(myString.charAt(0))) ...`

Comment: @rossum I like that but also make sure the string has a length of 1.

Answer (score 7):

Since you are testing for a single digit in the range one to nine, you could use a regular expression. Like,

```
if (input.matches("[1-9]")) {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You didn't include '0' in your sample code, but I assume you'd want to include that.  The most readable and straightforward way would be

```
if (input.length == 1 && Character.isDigit(input[0]))
{ 
    //... 
}
```

But you could also do it this way:

```
if (input.length == 1 && input[0] >= 48 && input[0] <= 57)
{
    //you can change 48 to 49 if you want to exclude 0
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the elegant answer of @Elliott Frisch, the following will also serve the purpose:

**A.**

```
if(input.length() == 1 && Character.isDigit(input.charAt(0)) && input.charAt(0) != '0') {
    // ...
}
```

**B.**

```
if(input.length() == 1 && Character.isDigit(input.charAt(0)) && input.charAt(0) != 48) {
    // ...
}
```

**C.**

```
try {
    if (Integer.parseInt(input) > 0 && Integer.parseInt(input) < 10) {
        // ...
    }
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use regex "[0-9]" like `input.matches("[0-9]")`.
"[0-9]" indicates that the one character should be a digit.

Here is a code in Java that tells you if given number is a single digit number or not.

```
public static void main (String[] args)
{
    String input = "1";
    System.out.println(input.matches("[0-9]"));
}
```